# Why does this linked list insert code work, and the other code doesn't?

Tags: java

I'm learning linked lists in Java and I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
public static Node insert(Node head, int data) {
    if (head == null) return new Node(data);
    else {
        Node tail = head;
        while (tail != null) tail = tail.next;
        tail = new Node(data);
        return head;
    }
}
```

While this works very well:

```
public static Node insert(Node head, int data) {
    if (head == null) return new Node(data);
    else {
        Node tail = head;
        while (tail.next != null) tail = tail.next;
        tail.next = new Node(data);
        return head;
    }
}
```

In both codes the null end nodes are instantiated. Why does not this produce the same result?

The Node class is as follows:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: '*`instancialized`*'

Comment: In both cases for the `head==null` case you forgot to set `head` to the new node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you are creating a new `Node` but not connecting it at anything, so it will just be detached from the list.

In the second case you are creating a new `Node` and connecting it to your actual tail `Node`, so it will be attached to the list.

Here a graphical representation:

[image: linked list insert]

Comment: Why in the first case `tail` starts pointing to null if I set `tail = head`, being `head` not null?

Comment: @HugoB The first part is the situation just before `new Node(data)`, so just after the `while` loop. In the first case, after the loop, `tail` is null because that is the exit condition of the `while` loop; in other words, `while (tail != null)` means that after the loop `tail` will be `null`.

Comment: But even if in the first case `tail` is not connecting to anything, `head`, which will be returned, should it not be connected to `tail` and have its value?

Comment: I mean, if `tail` assumes the null position of `tail.next`, after passing `new Node` `head` should it not reach the previous `tail` pointer and, through it, `tail.next`?

Comment: when `tail.next` is `null` the situation is NOT like `o->o->null`, `null` means that it's not pointing to anything, not that it is pointing to something which is `null`; the situation is like in the image in the answer, so `o->o`. Therefore when `tail` assumes "that" `null`, it's not a special position in the memory that is pointed by `tail.next`, it just means that it is nothing, exactly like `Node anotherNode = null`, so `tail = new Node(data);` is exactly like `anotherNode = new Node(data);`, there is no relation with the list. `tail.next` is still `null`, not pointing to anything.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I was thinking the concept wrongly. Thank you, you've been a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (tail != null) tail = tail.next;
```

The loop terminates when `tail.next` is null.

Then you do this:

```
tail = new Node(data);
```

Which leaves the `next` pointer of the last non-null `tail` to be null.

---

```
[head]---[1 (head.next)]---[2 (1.next)]---...---...---[last]---[nil (last.next)]
```

Comment: The loop ends when `tail` is null, **not** `tail.next`. So, the null `tail` pointer at the end should not be null.

Comment: Why `tail` becomes null? because it gets assigned to the `next` of the last non-null `tail`, which is null.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `Node` class to below.

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        this.data = d;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Set your head to new node in case you are inserting the first node.

```
public static Node insert(Node head, int data) {
    if (head == null) {
         head = new Node(data);
         return head;
    }
    else {
        Node tail = head;
        while (tail.next != null) tail = tail.next;
        tail.next = new Node(data);
        return head;
    }
}
```

The reason why your first case is not working because below will attach the node not after it rather you are creating a new node altogether and assigning it to your current pointed node.

```
while (tail != null) tail = tail.next;
        tail = new Node(data);
```

Comment: Didn't read the question properly. Hope the downvote will be taken back now.

Comment: Yeah, but in the first case `if (head == null)`, I assign the new node to my current node, `head`, and it works. Why? (The downvote is not mine.)

Comment: Correct. When head is null that means either your list is empty or your head is pointing to null. So to insert the first node you need to create a new node and set it to head.